# (de)Serialize from CSV to an object (or preferably a list of type object)

Tags: c#, serialization, csv

(I am a C++ programmer - trying to learn C# - and it appears that there are some built in object serialization - but I am a bit out of water here...)

I have been asked to load test data into a collection of objects from a CSV file. (CSV is preferred over xml because it is a heck of a lot simpler and readable to humans.  We are createing test data to run unit tests)

The collection will be a list of (simple) objects.

```
List<MyObject>
```

Where MyObject is a class that contains a few doubles and a few ints.

What is the preferred way to do this?  I don't think I will ever have a need to serialize just one of these objects.

I would expect that one single line represents one object, and the set of lines in the file is used to make the list/collection.

Answer (score 8):

Below should do the trick, just did this a couple months ago for data conversion project i was working on.

A major note to anyone doing CSV (or any character delimited strings), you really should look at using a specific library suited for it. The most popular one I've found is below (pretty tried and true)

You'll start with `string.Split(',')` and then what do you do when someone accidentally throws a comma in your test data file? ... it's just nightmare after nightmare and this library has traversed most of that for you:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx?msg=3227161

```
using System.IO;
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;

static class Program
{

    public class MyObject
    {
        public int Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
        public decimal Prop3 { get; set; }
    }

    void ReadCsv()
    {
        //holds the property mappings
        Dictionary<string, int> myObjectMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        List<MyObject> myObjectList = new List<MyObject>();

        // open the file "data.csv" which is a CSV file with headers
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader("data.csv"), true))
        {
            int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;
            string[] headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders();

            for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
            {
                myObjectMap[headers[i]] = i; // track the index of each column name
            }

            while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
            {
                MyObject myObj = new MyObject();

                myObj.Prop1 = csv[myObjectMap["Prop1"]];
                myObj.Prop2 = csv[myObjectMap["Prop2"]];
                myObj.Prop3 = csv[myObjectMap["Prop3"]];

                myObjectList.Add(myObj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by CSV file with Headers? What if I just have data that isn't organized in a way of row by column and I still wanted to parse through the data?

Answer (score 5):

Hate to give out links but this one has the exact sample you're looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513866.aspx#Y154

Comment: this shows splitting items by comma. not recommended for those data fields that may have a quoted string containing commas.  See other answer above using CsvReader