# Need Help Pulling Data From A File

Tags: c#, streamreader

I'm learning how to read and write to external text files with C#(yes, this is classwork, getting that out of the way now), and I've kind of hit a wall. See, the first part of this assignment was to create a program that can write customer records to an external file, after creating a Customer class with ID number, name, and current balance fields, which I did.

My predicament is that I now have to create a program to search the file I created with that first one, and print out each line to the console with a balance greater than or equal to a minimum balance supplied by a user. I'm drawing a blank on how to actually do this.

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;
using System.IO;

namespace FindCustomerRecords2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Intialize variables
            double minBal;
            string line;

            //Prompt user to enter minimum balance and store in minBal
            Write("Please enter a minimum balance to pull up\n" +
                  "all customers that owe at least that much.");
            minBal = Convert.ToDouble(ReadLine());

            //Open data stream to CustomerRecords.txt
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"H:\C#\Visual C# 2015\Ch. 14 - Files and Streams\CustomerRecords.txt");
            //Loop through CustomerRecords.txt, find values
            //greater than or euqal to minBal, and display
            //each line with such a value
            while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'm not looking to be fed an answer, I just genuinely don't know what to use to accomplish what I've been asked to do. Anyone willing to help me out?

**EDIT:** I eventually found out what I was doing wrong. For the future reference of anyone who may have the same problem in the future: I got it to work by using Split() to assign the data to an array called fields, then assigned each array position of fields to variables called id, name, and balance, and compared each balance to minBal in an if statement like so:

```html
fields = recordIn.Split(DELIM);
                id = Convert.ToInt32(fields[0]);
                name = fields[1];
                balance = Convert.ToDouble(fields[2]);
```

Thanks to everyone who replied.

Comment: What does the file look like?

Comment: When you debug this, what is the value of `line` in that loop?  Does it contain the value you're trying to compare?

Comment: @Joe Healy 
It's just a simple CSV text file with some fake values in it.

45454, Glenn Matthews, 54.87
10000, Jerry Rice, 150.45
58546, Klein Botteau, 45

That's the entire contents right there, as far as I've added. The first application accepts user input, uses that to instantiate an object from a Customer class I created, then passes the values from the object to the CustomerRecords.txt file.

Comment: @David The value of line changes as it loops through the external CustomerRecords.txt file. It changes to each different line of the file as it loops: 
45454, Glenn Matthews, 54.87
10000, Jerry Rice, 150.45
58546, Klein Botteau, 45

Comment: when you declare variables it's generally best to initialize to something preferably to their default value for starters. For example `double minBal = 0d;` and `string line = string.empty;` also use the debugger and tell us what the actual error and or issue is.

Comment: @TylerMerrill: So are you just asking how to get a substring from a string to compare it with another value?

Comment: @David What I'm trying to do, according to the assignment, is take a minimum value from user input, compare it to the records in the text file, and display only the records that have greater than or equal to that value. Say that the user enters "50" for the minimum value; I would want to display only Glenn Matthews and Jerry Rice's entries to the console. So...yes? Maybe?

Comment: read this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688221/deserialize-from-csv-to-an-object-or-preferably-a-list-of-type-object .  Good guidelines there.  The format you are using is called "CSV".

Comment: @MethodMan My problem isn't an error. The application starts up just fine. I just am not sure how to actually do what the prompt is asking me to do, because I can't find where or when the book explains how to do it. My question is, what do I need to do to take a given value of minBal, compare it to the records in the file, and display only the records that have a balance greater than or equal to minBal?

Comment: It's hard to say because I'm not sure of what you're expected to know at this point. Like, I'm not sure if you're supposed to be using the .Split() function yet and I'm also assuming you're not supposed to be using 3rd party libraries, but I don't know if that's true either.

Comment: Within your while loop maybe think about how you can get access to each of the comma-delimited values " 45454, Glenn Matthews, 54.87" What tools do you have that could do that? Is there some way inside of your line variable you can look for that? Hmmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a closer look inside of your while loop:

```
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{

}
```

at this point inside of the loop, you should have the following data:

`45454, Glenn Matthews, 54.87`

If not, then you created your CSV file incorrectly. Let's assume for now that you created it correctly. How would you go about getting the value out of your `line` variable in order to compare it to your `minBal` variable? If you can figure that part out then you can probably solve the rest on your own.

What tools (such as string methods) do you have at your disposal that could help do this?

There might also be Stream/StreamReader methods that could help you out as well. Good luck!

Comment: Like you mentioned in the comment above, this chapter is dealing with the Split() method, yes. Third-party libraries, not so much...In the first version of this program, I also used Contains() to pull data, and Seek() has been used in this chapter as well. The chapter is about Filestreams and Serialization.